# Ubuntu is slow and I don't know why

Tags: 12.04

I've been an XP user forever and I still am. Yesterday wanted to try Ubuntu I installed it and its very very slow on my computer. Here's my computer specs intel celeron(R) 2.40 GHz 1 gb of memory . Did I do something wrong because I heard Ubuntu is really fast. When I look in system monitor it says the the CPU is constantly at 100 %.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's because Ubuntu is using your CPU (which barely makes the cut) to handle GPU code for the Unity interface. Use Additional Drivers (`jockey-gtk` or Software Sources > Additional Drivers tab) to see if there are graphics drivers available for your system. If not, you may want to consider buying a better computer. Or, since those are very minimal specs for Ubuntu, you may want to try [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/), [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/), or even [Kubuntu](http://www.kubuntu.org/) (which is also somewhat cumbersome), all official variants of Ubuntu, or even a whole different distro; [there are plenty out there](http://distrowatch.com/).

Comment: I don't think the conclusion it is Unity is warranted given the information presented.

Comment: As searchfgold6789 suggested, use an Ubuntu derivative that will not require more from your graphics card and cpu.  Lubuntu or Xubuntu are quite zippy; you'll like them, and you will still have access to all of the community support and software you would get to use if you had Ubuntu installed.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal window, and run the command `top` to see what might be hitting your CPU so hard. Something is probably misbehaving and this is the first step to finding out what it might be.

Comment: Seems to be 1015 root what is that

Comment: The rightmost column will tell you the name of the process which will allow us to make a more educated guess at what the problem is.